# Floating point exception in OpenAcc Merge Sort program

Tags: c, openacc

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <openacc.h>
#define THR 10


//Function to test if the output is in asending order or not
void test(int a[], int n) {
int i;
for (i=1;i<n;++i) {
if (a[i]<a[i-1]) {
  break;
}
}
if (i<n) { 
for (i=1;i<n;++i) {  
   if (a[i]>a[i-1]){
      break;
   }
 }
if (i<n) {
  printf("\nArray is not sorted\n");
}
}
else {
printf("\nArray is sorted\n");
}
}

 /* Function to sort an array using insertion sort in serial*/
void isort (int *array, int low, int mid, int high) {

for (int i = mid; i <= high; i++) {
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (array[i] < array [j]) {
            int holder = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = holder;
            i--;
        }
    }
 }
 }
/* Function to merge */
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);

// Utility function to find minimum of two integers
#pragma acc routine seq
int min(int x, int y) { return (x<y)? x :y; }

/* Iterative mergesort function to sort arr[0...n-1] */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int n)
{
int curr_size;  // For current size of subarrays to be merged
               // curr_size varies from 1 to n/2
int left_start; // For picking starting index of left subarray
               // to be merged
#pragma acc kernels //pcopy(arr[0:n1])// pcopying (R[0:n2])
      { 
 #pragma acc loop independent
  for (curr_size=1; curr_size<=n-1; curr_size = 2*curr_size)
 {
  #pragma acc loop independent
   // Pick starting point of different subarrays of current size
   for (left_start=0; left_start<n-1; left_start += 2*curr_size)
   {
       // Find ending point of left subarray. mid+1 is starting 
       // point of right
       int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;

       int right_end = min(left_start + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1);

       // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid] & arr[mid+1...right_end]
       merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
   }
 }
}}

/* Function to merge the two haves arr[l..m] and arr[m+1..r] of array arr[] 
*/
 #pragma acc routine vector
 void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
int i, j, k;
int n1 = m - l + 1;
int n2 =  r - m;

/* create temp arrays */
int *L, *R;
 L = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n1); 
 R = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n2);     
/* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
 #pragma acc loop independent 
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    L[i] = arr[l + i];
 #pragma acc loop independent 
for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

/* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
i = 0;
j = 0;
k = l;

#pragma acc loop independent private(k) reduction(+:j) private (L[0:n1]) private (R[0:n1]) private (arr[0:n1])reduction(+:i)
      //  private(k) reduction(+:j)
while (i < n1 && j < n2)
{
    if (L[i] <= R[j])
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there are any */

#pragma acc loop seq private (arr[0:n2]) 
while (i < n1)
{
    arr[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there are any */
#pragma acc loop seq private (arr[0:n2]) 
while (j < n2)
{
    arr[k] = R[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
free(L);
free(R);
}


/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
printf("\n");
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
 {
 int i, n=20, *a;
 double startTime, endTime;

 printf("How many elements in the array? ");

 a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);        
 srand(time(0));
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
         a[i]=rand()%1000;
       }    
 printf("List Before Sorting...\n");
 printArray(a, n);
 if (n<=THR) 
 {
 startTime = omp_get_wtime();
 isort(a,0,0,n); 
 endTime = omp_get_wtime();
 printf("\nSorted array:  ");
 printArray(a,n);
 printf("\n");
 test(a,n);
 printf("IN");
 printf("\nTime: %g\n",endTime-startTime);
 exit(0);
 }       

 else 
 {
 startTime = omp_get_wtime();
 mergeSort(a,n); 
 endTime = omp_get_wtime();
 printf("\nSorted array:  ");
 printArray(a,n);
 printf("\n");
 test(a,n);
 printf("ACC");
 printf("\nTime: %g\n",endTime-startTime);
 printf("\nSize of the array is %d",n);

 exit(0);
 }      
 }
```

After reading plenty of articles in PGI forum and help of @MAT from stackoverflow, I managed to resolve most of the errors and now I am using iterative Merge Sort instead of recursive as I found that OpenAcc doesn't work well with recursive functions. Now, I have only one error remaining this is in merge function:-

109, Loop without integer trip count will be executed in sequential mode

And I read http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?p=17748&sid=0aa1537bdc68fc1f6fac74f66a788970 also but can't get certain idea to use it in my program. Because of this error, my result is:-

How many elements in the array? List Before Sorting...
801 673 288 374 516 908 473 130 874 928 491 406 276 302 186 442 865 341 624 725
Floating point exception

It's saying floating point exception even when I am using integers in my program.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Remove the unrelated tag. And read [ask].

Comment: done, removed, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Can you post the full reproducing example or provide a link to it?  If so, I'll take a look and see what I can determine.

Comment: @MatColgrove I have updated the entire code.

Comment: Also now the output is generating 3 digit numbers but unsorted.

Comment: I made some changes in the program, also now I checked that in output I am getting most of the elements more than once although in the input it occurred only once:-The unsorted a is:205  831  382  842  137  757  112 21 ......Sorted a:21  21  66  66  112  112  137  149  149  171  ...Array is not sorted. for example, in unsorted array 21 is only once but in output its twice.

Comment: I am using now iterative merge sort algorithm as I though with that it would be easy to avoid recursive parallelism, although now I am getting :-PGC-S-0155-Procedures called in a compute region must have acc routine information: min (mer_acc.c: 135)
PGC-S-0155-Accelerator region ignored; see -Minfo messages  (mer_acc.c: 123)
this error for min function.

Comment: I'm seeing unsorted arrays even when compiled without optimization and without OpenACC.  So there's something wrong with your algorithm rather than anything to do with the OpenACC code.  Though, the data regions around the while loops are extraneous since you're computing on the host.

Comment: As for the missing device "min" routine, are you defining your own "min" routine?  If so, you need to decorate the definition with "acc routine" so the compiler knows to create a device version of the routine.  (or inline the routine by adding the -Minline compiler flag).  Also you can use the standard "fmin" by including the PGI supplied "accelmath.h" header file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as per your guidance I used fmin instead of min, although still I am getting same error. int right_end = fmin (x , n-1);

Comment: Apologies, now, it's not giving error for min, it's same error but for merge function.

Comment: # pragma acc kernels 
    # pragma acc loop independent gang (1), worker(1)  
   for (curr_size=1; curr_size<=n-1; curr_size = 2*curr_size)
   {
      # pragma acc loop independent vector
       for (left_start=0; left_start<n-1; left_start += 2*curr_size)
       { int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;
           int x = left_start + 2*curr_size - 1;
           int right_end = fmin (x , n-1);           
      if ((right_end - left_start) > THR)
           merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
         else 
        isort(arr, left_start,mid, right_end);}}} This is mergesort.

Comment: I was reading PGI forum http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=5583&highlight=pgcs0155procedures+called+compute+region+acc+routine+information and found someone has similar issue while calling function inside the kernel, but the solution is not clear to me. Can someone explain me.

Comment: I doubt that post is related.  Basically, in order to be able to call a function from within a compute region, the function you're calling needs to have a device version available.  (i.e. you can't call a host function from the device).  Adding a  "acc routine" directive to the prototype and definition of the function is how you indicate to the compiler to create a device version of the function.  Some system functions are available on the device (such as "fmin" if you add "#include <accelmath.h>" to get the correct definition), but if no device version is available, you may need to add it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the post, I also felt similar so now I changed my approach from recursive to iterative merge sort and now I am using kernel directive in merge and insertion sort function, instead of mergeSort function. Now I am not getting previous errors but correct code parallelization is hard to achieve.

Comment: Although I have one question, maybe it will look silly, but is there some other way to use kernels in all function without calling one kernel inside other.As if now I am not using the kernel in mergeSort so compiler is not calling that function for parallelization.

Comment: I know maybe I am asking more help from you, but I am really trying to run this program properly, but it's getting harder, if it's possible can you please run program from your end and help me to figure out the solution. I am using these compiler settings:-pgcc -acc -ta=nvidia:managed,time -Minfo=accel -Mautoinline  -o output mer_acc.c.

Comment: I would encourage you to go back and look at the original C, i.e. no OpenACC, version.  Run the executable multiple times and you will see that it will that it fails to sort the array on some of the runs.  I believe the problem is with your isort routine.  When I change the starting index of the outer loop from mid to left, it passes each time as does the OpenACC version.  I don't know if this is the proper fix, but something you should examine.

Comment: Yes @MatColgrove you are absolutely correct, I also found the same, that issue is with isort, although, the solution of changing starting index also doesn't seems proper.

Comment: @MatColgrove, I figured out almost all the issues and I have rephrased my question again, now I have only single error, I will really appreciate if you may please have a look on it.

Comment: I have changed independent to seq and the error is gone:- #pragma acc loop seq private(k) reduction(+:j) private (L[0:n1]) private (R[0:n1]) private (arr[0:n1])reduction(+:i)   However, the result is still floating point exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems here.

It looks like there can be a case where "mid" is greater that "right_end" which will cause a malloc to have a negative size.  While I'm not sure it's the correct fix, I added an if statement to skip the merge when mid>right_end.

Parallel loops must be countable, i.e. that the number of iterations is known at the start of the loop.  Hence you can't put "loop" directives around while loops.

Putting "arr" in a private clause isn't what you want here.  You want to update the global array, not a private copy.  Private will make a private copy of the variable for every gang, vector, or worker (depending upon the schedule of the loop with the private clause).  The private variable goes away after the kernel executes.

Also your "curr_size" for loop has a dependency so can't be parallelized.  The problem here is that it strides by "curr_size=2*curr_size".  Each iteration needs the previous iteration's curr_size value before it can compute it's own curr_size.

Note that using "malloc" within a compute region is problematic.  First, device side mallocs are very slow so will have an adverse impact on performance.  Also, the heap on the device is quite small (default 8MB but can be increased but setting the environment variable PGI_ACC_HEAPSIZE) so very large values of n may overflow the heap and give an illegal address error.

Here's the fixed code:

```
% cat test.c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <openacc.h>
#define THR 10


//Function to test if the output is in asending order or not
void test(int a[], int n) {
int i;
for (i=1;i<n;++i) {
if (a[i]<a[i-1]) {
  break;
}
}
if (i<n) {
for (i=1;i<n;++i) {
   if (a[i]>a[i-1]){
      break;
   }
 }
if (i<n) {
  printf("\nArray is not sorted\n");
}
}
else {
printf("\nArray is sorted\n");
}
}

 /* Function to sort an array using insertion sort in serial*/
void isort (int *array, int low, int mid, int high) {

for (int i = mid; i <= high; i++) {
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (array[i] < array [j]) {
            int holder = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = holder;
            i--;
        }
    }
 }
 }
/* Function to merge */
void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);

// Utility function to find minimum of two integers
#pragma acc routine seq
int min(int x, int y) { return (x<y)? x :y; }

/* Iterative mergesort function to sort arr[0...n-1] */
void mergeSort(int arr[], int n)
{
int curr_size;  // For current size of subarrays to be merged
               // curr_size varies from 1 to n/2
int left_start; // For picking starting index of left subarray
               // to be merged
#pragma acc data copy(arr[0:n])// pcopying (R[0:n2])
      {
  for (curr_size=1; curr_size<=n-1; curr_size = 2*curr_size)
 {
  #pragma acc parallel loop
   // Pick starting point of different subarrays of current size
   for (left_start=0; left_start<n-1; left_start += 2*curr_size)
   {
       // Find ending point of left subarray. mid+1 is starting
       // point of right
       int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;

       int right_end = min(left_start + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1);

       // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid] & arr[mid+1...right_end]
       if (mid < right_end) merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
   }
 }
}}

/* Function to merge the two haves arr[l..m] and arr[m+1..r] of array arr[]
*/
 #pragma acc routine(merge) vector
 void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
int i, j, k;
int n1 = m - l + 1;
int n2 =  r - m;

/* create temp arrays */
int *L, *R;
 L = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n1);
 R = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n2);
/* Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[] */
 #pragma acc loop independent
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    L[i] = arr[l + i];
 #pragma acc loop independent
for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
    R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

/* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
i = 0;
j = 0;
k = l;

while (i < n1 && j < n2)
{
    if (L[i] <= R[j])
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there are any */

while (i < n1)
{
    arr[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there are any */
while (j < n2)
{
    arr[k] = R[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
free(L);
free(R);
}


/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int A[], int size)
{
int i;
for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
printf("\n");
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
 {
 int i, n=100, *a;
 double startTime, endTime;

 printf("How many elements in the array? ");

 a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
 srand(time(0));
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
         a[i]=rand()%1000;
       }
 printf("List Before Sorting...\n");
 printArray(a, n);
 if (n<=THR)
 {
 startTime = omp_get_wtime();
 isort(a,0,0,n);
 endTime = omp_get_wtime();
 printf("\nSorted array:  ");
 printArray(a,n);
 printf("\n");
 test(a,n);
 printf("IN");
 printf("\nTime: %g\n",endTime-startTime);
 exit(0);
 }

 else
 {
 startTime = omp_get_wtime();
 mergeSort(a,n);
 endTime = omp_get_wtime();
 printf("\nSorted array:  ");
 printArray(a,n);
 printf("\n");
 test(a,n);
 printf("ACC");
 printf("\nTime: %g\n",endTime-startTime);
 printf("\nSize of the array is %d\n",n);

 exit(0);
 }
 }

% pgcc -Minfo=accel -acc test.c -fast -o gpu
min:
     51, Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
mergeSort:
     60, Generating copy(arr[:n])
     64, Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         66, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.x */
merge:
     84, Generating Tesla code
         95, #pragma acc loop vector /* threadIdx.x */
         98, #pragma acc loop vector /* threadIdx.x */
        106, #pragma acc loop seq
        123, #pragma acc loop seq
        131, #pragma acc loop seq
     95, Loop is parallelizable
     98, Loop is parallelizable
    106, Loop carried scalar dependence for i at line 119,126,125
         Loop carried scalar dependence for j at line 106,108
         Loop carried scalar dependence for i at line 111,110
         Loop carried scalar dependence for j at line 116
         Scalar last value needed after loop for i at line 123
         Loop carried scalar dependence for j at line 134,133
         Loop carried scalar dependence for i at line 108
         Loop carried scalar dependence for j at line 115
    110, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: k
    115, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: k
    118, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: k
% ./gpu
How many elements in the array? List Before Sorting...
58 612 99 182 914 802 452 229 856 644 932 339 650 915 533 300 456 892 860 764 866 229 400 561 328 170 573 121 364 392 801 775 356 901 309 622 703 762 851 911 406 135 602 56 51 136 708 507 380 568 623 246 797 24 160 125 194 733 599 910 477 400 685 185 653 995 808 709 109 659 972 867 147 575 276 198 711 984 57 91 553 680 689 702 56 849 828 602 935 779 865 412 179 550 598 185 897 758 894 6

Sorted array:  6 24 51 56 56 57 58 91 99 109 121 125 135 136 147 160 170 179 182 185 185 194 198 229 229 246 276 300 309 328 339 356 364 380 392 400 400 406 412 452 456 477 507 533 550 553 561 568 573 575 598 599 602 602 612 622 623 644 650 653 659 680 685 689 702 703 708 709 711 733 758 762 764 775 779 797 801 802 808 828 849 851 856 860 865 866 867 892 894 897 901 910 911 914 915 932 935 972 984 995


Array is sorted
ACC
Time: 1.26239

Size of the array is 100
```

Comment: Dear @MatColgrove thanks for explaining and providing the solution so well. Although, in oder to check performance and efficiency of the code, I was calculating time w.r.t. different number of gangs and vectors, however, now with parallel directive it's giving :-PGCC-S-0155-Illegal context for gang(num:) or worker(num:) or vector(length:)  (acc_mer.cpp: 69)
PGCC/x86 Linux 16.10-0: compilation completed with severe errors
error and with kernels directive its giving:- PGCC-S-0155-vector(x) not allowed in a kernels region having vector_length  error.

Comment: For "parallel", you can only use the "num_gang", "num_worker" and "vector_length" clauses on the "parallel" directive.  For "kernels", you can "gang(num)", "worker(num)", and "vector(length)" on individual loop directives.  The reason is that with "parallel", only a single device kernel is created so all loops within the region need the same values.  With "kernels", multiple device kernels may be created so the values can change per loop.  Note that these restrictions maybe lifted in the OpenACC 2.6 standard, but are still enforced by the 16.10 and 17.4 PGI compilers.

Comment: Thanks again for explanation, now I am using #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(1), vector_length(128)
      {
    #pragma acc loop gang, vector.